# When iterating through CSV file and printing the rows, only the first row gets printed

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've loaded a CSV file using Pandas. The CSV file has 4000 rows.
It loaded correctly. When printing out the data frame, all 4000 rows are printed.
But when I iterate through the rows using a "for" loop, it only prints the first row in the file.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('EX2_EM_GMM.csv')
for sample in df:
    print sample
```

An Ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

For iterating over `DataFrame` rows you can use [.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) function.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Process each row
```

Answer (score 2):

> In your case I think following examples provide solution and also
>   providing time of execution. for this amount of rows I will use **itertuples()**

[itertuples()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and [iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

di = {k:np.random.randn(4000) for k in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(di)

for row in df.itertuples():
    print row

%timeit [row for row in df.itertuples()]

%timeit [row for row in df.iterrows()]
```

[image: output sample]
[image: result of execution time]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use iterrows() to loop through each of the rows. The default iteration will just show the columns.

```
for sample in df.iterrows():
    print sample
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!